# How to sum over two indices in python?

Tags: python, numpy, sum

Can someone help me out with the `sum` function ?

I am trying to sum over two indices. I want to obtain the following result:

```
p_t[0, 0]+p_t[0, 1]+p_t[0, 2]+p_t[1, 0]+p_t[1, 1]+p_t[1, 2]+p_t[2,0]+p_t[2, 1]+p_t[2, 2]
```

, using this code:

```
num_products=3
sum (p_t[i, j] for i,j in range(num_products))
```

But I get the error:

> TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in ()
>       ----> 1 sum (p_t[i, j] for i,j in range(num_products))
>        in (***failed resolving arguments***)
>       TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I also tried this but did not work either

```
sum (p_t[i, j] for i in range(num_products) for j in range(num_products))
```

Comment: are you using numpy?  also, if you want a list comprehension, surround it with square brackets.

Comment: numpy library is also imported already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum(p_t[i][j] for i in range(len(p_t)) for j in range(len(p_t[i])))
```

Comment: It gives error  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-50ece11c37a1> in <module>()
----> 1 sum(p_t[i, j] for i in range(len(p_t)) for j in range(len(p_t[i])))
      2 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Independent'

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `p_t` actually contains?

Comment: There was a mistake the way I indexed `p_t`, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

a =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,3,3]]
p_t = np.array(a)
num_products = 3

rslt1 = sum (p_t[i, j] for i,j in product(range(num_products), repeat=2))

rslt2= sum (p_t[i, j] for i in range(num_products) for j in range(num_products))
```

**Output:**

```
rslt1
Out[79]: 30

rslt2
Out[80]: 30
```

For your first attempt, you can actually use `itertools.product`.

For your second attempt, Actually, your `sum (p_t[i, j] for i in range(num_products) for j in range(num_products))` works from my side.

---

Generally, below two are equivalent when it comes to the product of two list

```
In [88]: [(i,j) for i in range(2) for j in range(3)]
Out[88]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]

In [89]: [x for x in product(range(2), range(3))]
Out[89]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: It gives error also :( File "<ipython-input-51-92706d77a17b>", line 3
    sum (p_t[i, j] for i,j in product(range(num_products), repeat=2)
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Zeir, I can run the code on both Python2.7 and Python3.3.  How come it give a syntax error? DO you indent correctly when you copy/paste my code?